# CSS overlay and screen blend modes look different on phone and laptop

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I am trying to use blend modes for a website for a project, but I've found that they look different on my phone browser (chrome v 78.0.3904.84 on iphone 7) to my browser on my laptop (chrome v 78.0.3904.97 on mac).
[It looks like this on the laptop,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWCQg.png) [and like this on the phone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZqu6.png)
So far as I can tell, both browsers support mix-blend-modes, so I'm not sure what's different.
The code for the elements that are being blended is:

```
    .GraphButton {
    font-size: calc(10px + 8vmin);
    font-weight: 300;
    color: var(--button-text);
    background: var(--main-yellow);
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
    height: 27vh;
    width: 35vw;
    margin: auto 6vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is a div on top of an svg background image. There is no transform involved.

Does anyone know what could be causing the difference or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mix-blend-mode is not supported on SVG elements in Safari and iOS Safari, but it IS supported for SVG elements in chrome. See https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode

Comment: I am using chrome on both, just different devices.  It's not that it's not blending at all, it's blending differently.

Comment: Chrome on iOS still is forced to use Webkit to render. it is a restriction placed by apple. see this link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/350671/does-safari-and-google-chrome-for-macos-use-the-same-rendering-engine